# Reset lastexitcode if robocopy succeeds with powershell

Tags: powershell, gitlab-ci

I'm using `robocopy` to copy files during a build step in a Gitlab pipeline. The pipeline tasks are executed in powershell.

The exit status of `robocopy` results in a failure of my build step. I noticed all statuscodes under 8 are valid. Meaning I should reset the `$lastexitcode` to `$null` if the `$lastexitcode` is `< 8`

This is what I tried in my powershell script:

```
robocopy src dest /mir (&{if ($lastexitcode -lt 8) { $global:LASTEXITCODE = $null }})
```

The problem here is that the `(&{ if...` part is executed before `robocopy`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must use two statements, separated by `;`:

```
robocopy src dest /mir; if ($lastexitcode -lt 8) { $global:LASTEXITCODE = $null }
```

In your attempt the (in this case empty) *output* of the `(...)` expression was passed as an *argument to `robocopy`* and, as you've observed, expressions passed as arguments are (of necessity) evaluated *first*.

Note: Robocopy's exit codes `0` through `7` are *non-error* exit codes, hence the `-le 8` condition - see https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy-exit.html

Comment: Might wanna use `-le 1` as exit codes 2 and 4 are warnings. Exit code 1 means successful copying, exit code 0 means no files were copied.

Comment: Thanks, @GChuf. It looks like the OP's intent was to act on true _errors_ only (exit code 8 or above). I've added a link to the answer that documents Robocopy's exit codes.